# @auth directive with 'userPools' provider found, but the project has no Cognito User Pools authentication provider configured

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-userpools

When I am trying to do "amplify push" This error message shows in my ide console.

**× An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
@auth directive with 'userPools' provider found, but the project has no Cognito User Pools authentication provider configured.**

Can someone help me with this matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to run:

```
amplify update api

? Please select from one of the below mentioned services: GraphQL
? Select from the options below Walkthrough all configurations
? Choose the default authorization type for the API Amazon Cognito User Pool
Use a Cognito user pool configured as a part of this project.
? Do you want to configure advanced settings for the GraphQL API No, I am done.
```

Then run:

```
amplify push
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is very easy to think the answer is in `amplify auth update` given the nature of the query. This worked perfectly for me - thanks!

Comment: This answer is no longer correct for me:
I got 

? Select a setting to edit
? Choose the default authorization type for the API

Comment: Worked for me! Actually, ones can assume adding the Annotation in the Schema, the authorization config is also configured, what is not the case. Calling amplify update api is necessary. I would add that checking the access for each entity calling `amplify status api -acm <EntityName>` also facilitates troubleshooting authorization problems.